# Recreate nonunique index for bulk load

Tags: oracle, indexing, constraints

I have simple table with `foreign key` (for single column) and `nonunique index` for column involved in a `FK`. I disable `FK` before `bulk load` (before bulk load I `truncate` table), and enable it after. I know that in Oracle when you disable a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY constraint` an associated index is dropped. And when you enable a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint an associated index is created. But what about disabling/enabling `FK`? Should I manually drop `nonunique index` for `FK` before bulk load and also manually create `nonunique index` after? Or I can keep that index (I mean would this index be valid if I kept him)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first disable the `INDEX`

```
ALTER INDEX idx_fk_column UNUSABLE;
```

then after your DML operations re-build it.

```
ALTER INDEX idx_fk_column REBUILD;
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice options. I think it's better than recreate index.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the index it is still valid.  But it may be an overhead during the load.  So, some sites prefer to disable (using UNUSABLE) and reenable (using REBUILD) such non-unique indexes (Note : If it is a Unique index, setting UNUSABLE would prevent INSERTs, so you'd have to actually DROP and CREATE).